# Pythonic way to join list and wrap result with same separator

Tags: python

I need to convert list `['a', 'b', 'c']` to string `'/a/b/c/'`

This example does not look like a good practice:

```
'/' + '/'.join(['a','b','c']) + '/'
>>> '/a/b/c/'
```

**EDIT**

@TomDalton asked a very good question:

> What do you want an empty list to result in? '', '/', or '//'?

I want single slash `'/'` in case of empty list.

How about this:

```
'/' + ''.join([i + '/' for i in ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

?

Comment: What do you want an empty list to result in? `''`, `'/'`, or `'//'`?

Comment: Why do you say that it doesn't look good? Looks just fine to me, is using the join to do it which is fast and easy.

Comment: Your solution looks absolutely fine for me. Alternatively, you could do something like `'/{}/'.format('/'.join(lst))`

Comment: Your solution does look fine to me. Here's an alternative: `'/{}/'.format('/'.join(somelist))`

Comment: @TomDalton, it will never be empty, but `'/'` is preferred for empty list

Comment: @MaximKoroteyev That's an odd default case, and would require special casing in any way I can think of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you have given is fine. You could using string formatting to make it look a little nicer:

```
'/{0}/'.format('/'.join(['a', 'b'. 'c'])
```

Or in the future in 3.6 with [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
f"/{format('/'.join(['a', 'b'. 'c'])}/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add two empty strings to the list:

```
>>> "/".join(['', 'a', 'b', 'c', ''])
'/a/b/c/'
```

Comment: While this would work, I don't think it's any clearer, and probably won't perform as well as the alternative (assuming that in a real scenario this would require appending an element to both ends of a list).